# Php script, explode() crashes apache?

Tags: php, apache, crash

I encountered a very strange bug.
Configuration:

- Win XP SP 3
- EasyPHP 5.3.8.1

  - PHP 5.3.8 VC9
  - Apache 2.2.19 VC9,
  - MySQL 5.5.16
  - PhpMyAdmin 3.4.5
  - Xdebug 2.1.2

I recently noticed that some part of my site kills apache. I found out that there's an `explode()` function call causing this. If I comment this function, the site loads well, but if not, apache crashes. I didn't find any strange parameters in it (`explode ('|', $val);`), the 2nd parameter is always a string.

But on the other hand, it should at least drop an error, and halt, not crash the whole server. Any ideas?

Comment: Any specific error messages you could share? How exactly does it crash?

Comment: no error message. Windows say "apache crashed, sorry, please send report blablabla" and then firefox say "there was a problem while loading"

Comment: try not to uncomment `explode` but put `exit;` after it. does it still crash?

Comment: Anything in the Apache error logs?

Comment: Try it on a Linux machine. I've sometimes made Apache crash on Windows 7 WAMP but never on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: no, then not. Its interesting, because it doesnt die right after the explode. The crast itself happens at the end of the script exection

Comment: nothing really in the apache log

Comment: the crash report says the php5ts.dll is responsible!

Comment: hmmm, I started apache/mysql manually, and IT DOESNT GET KILLED!

Comment: You should log `$val` and see what is the last logged value. Is it always the same?

Comment: Post source and error logs or this will be closed.

Comment: Can you post the value of $val? If you substitute some short string into $var, does that remove the error? Could it be an out-of-memory issue if your string is too long?